# PHP PDO Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am getting the following warning when I am trying to perform the following query.

Error

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters in E:\xampp\htdocs\msdca\attendance.php on line 142

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number in E:\xampp\htdocs\msdca\attendance.php on line 142
```

Query

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `st_id`, `st_name` FROM `students` WHERE st_name LIKE ? or st_phone LIKE ? AND atd_year = :year");
$param = array("%$name%", "%$name%");
$stmt-> bindValue(':year', $_GET['yid']);
$stmt-> execute($param);
```

What might be causing the problem here? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is exactly what the error message says, you are using positional parameters (`?`) and named parameters (`:year`) in the same query, which is not allowed. You need to consistently use one or the other e.g.

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `st_id`, `st_name` FROM `students` WHERE st_name LIKE ? or st_phone LIKE ? AND atd_year = ?");
$param = array("%$name%", "%$name%", $_GET['yid']);
$stmt-> execute($param);
```

or using named parameters:

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `st_id`, `st_name` FROM `students` WHERE st_name LIKE :name or st_phone LIKE :phone AND atd_year = :year");
$param = array(':name' => "%$name%", ':phone' => "%$name%", ':year' => $_GET['yid']);
$stmt-> execute($param);
```